# Difference between contains() and equality operator in C# for a HashSet and List with DateTime values?

Tags: c#, list, datetime, hashset

I want to store DateTime values in a data structure(either a HashSet or List).I later want to use that structure for comparison with some other DateTime values.

1. I want to know the different in mechanism of how "==" and contains() works.
2. Also I want to know the difference in mechanism with respect to HashSet and List types?
3. I assume contains () in HashSet would be O(1) vs O(n) in List?
4. What is more reliable to compare DateTime objects "==" or contains?
5. Is LINQ faster or the same?

Code -

```
List<DateTime> list1 = new List<DateTime>();
HashSet<DateTime> list2 = new HashSet<DateTime>();

list1.Add(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date));
list2.Add(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date));

DateTime someOtherDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

if(list1.Contains(someOtherDate))
 //thendosomething
VS
if(list2.Contains(someOtherDate))
 //thendosomething


AND 

foreach(DateTime tmpValue in list1)
{
  if(tmpValue == someOtherDate)
   //thendosomehting
}

VS

foreach(DateTime tmpValue in list2)
{
  if(tmpValue == someOtherDate)
   //thendosomehting
}
```

All of the above VS -

```
var rows = from e in list1
           where e == someOtherDate
           select e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the different in mechanism of how "==" and contains()
>   works.

`==` is checking two objects/structs for equality.  `List.Contains` and `HashSet.Contains` check if an object is contained within that list.

> Also I want to know the difference in mechanism with respect to
>   HashSet and List types?

`HashSet` is a hash table.  `List` is an array that can grow.

> I assume contains () in HashSet would be O(1) vs O(n) in List?

Yes

> What is more reliable to compare DateTime objects "==" or contains?

If you are checking if two `DateTime` values are equal, use `==`.  If you are checking if a collection contains a specific `DateTime`, use `Contains()`

Your `foreach` loops through the List are exactly what `List.Contains` is doing (but not at all what `HashSet.Contains` does)

Finally, your Linq query is going to create a new `IEnumerable<DateTime>` under the table, that evaluates O(N) over the list

Comment: What is contains in hashset doing?

Comment: It is doing a hashtable lookup O(1) to see if the value is there.  It by far is the most performant way to handle checking if a value exists in a collection-- assuming the collection size is significant.  If you only have 2 or 3 values in the collection, the List might be more performant